# & of a variable

Tags: c++, reference

I read somewhere that in C++ you can't give a definition like:

```
int& a;
```

but only:

```
int b;  
int& a=b;
```

Since `&` is a reference of the other variable, it cannot be defined separately.
On the other hand, I see it defined separately in code all the time.

Could someone explain to me how can you define

```
int & a;
```

without specifying a reference to which variable it is?

Comment: did you see that in class body?

Comment: yes. i think i saw it in a class body.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might see it in a class, but you need to assign it upon initialization in all constructors, e.g.

```
class X
{
    int & a;
public:
    X(int & i) :a(i) {}
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Considering the C++ standard, you cannot declare an unitialized reference by itself :

> There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references, and no pointers to references. The declaration of a reference shall contain an initializer (8.5.3) except when the declaration contains an explicit extern specifier (7.1.1), is a class member (9.2) declaration within a class declaration, or is the declaration of a parameter or a return type (8.3.5); see 3.1. A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function. [Note: in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by dereferencing a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior. As described in 9.6, a reference cannot be bound directly to a bitfield. ]
>
> —ISO/IEC 14882:1998(E), the ISO C++ standard, in section 8.3.2 [dcl.ref]

Answer (score 1):

& does not define an alias; it is a reference, which is like a stripped down pointer.  They cannot be reinitialized, which is why you must specify the "alias" at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to use a pointer. The reference notation comes down to the same as a pointer, only it cannot be null. That's why you cannot just declare a variable as `int & a`. Maybe there is an exception for members of a class (i.e. they can be defined as references), but the references have to be set in the constructor (see PigBen's answer).

Comment: -1: References cannot be reinitialized, and there are a few other restrictions on references